Problem generating code to populate Lists in a Protocol Buffer
I am having a problem with MapStruct 1.6.3. I am trying to map two POJOs to a ProtocolBuffer. My input is a Quote and a QuoteProcessingContext.
The issue is the way MapStruct is generating the code for repeated objects in the proto. The mapper is defined with
    @Mapper(
            componentModel = "spring",
            collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
            uses = { DateMapper.class, MailingAddressMapper.class, OptionMapper.class, TimestampMapper.class, VehicleMapper.class},
           injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)

I have defined the mappings:
    @Mapping(target = "vehiclesList", source = "quote.vehicles")
    @Mapping(target = "mailingAddressesList", source = "context.mailingAddress")

The accessor for vehicles returns List<PersonVehicle> and the accessor for mailing addresses returns List<MailingAddressProcessed>.
For vehicles, Mapstruct correctly generates
    if ( quote.getVehicles() != null ) {
        for ( PersonVehicle quoteVehicle : quote.getVehicles() ) {
            quote1.addVehicles( vehicleMapper.toProto( quoteVehicle ) );
        }
    }

For mailing addresses, it generates
     if ( quote1.getMailingAddressesList() != null ) {
        List<Address> list = mailingAddressProcessedListToAddressList( context.getMailingAddress() );
        if ( list != null ) {
            quote1.getMailingAddressesList().addAll( list );
        }
    }

    protected List<Address> mailingAddressProcessedListToAddressList(List<MailingAddressProcessed> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Address> list1 = new ArrayList<Address>( list.size() );
        for ( MailingAddressProcessed mailingAddressProcessed : list ) {
            list1.add( mailingAddressMapper.toProto( mailingAddressProcessed ) );
        }
        return list1;
    }

This does not work. We are trying addAll() on the immutable List returned by the proto instead of calling the addMailingAddresses() method in the proto.
Is there a way to fix this?
